# UIPickerView and NSUserDefaults issue

Tags: uipickerview, nsuserdefaults

I have an UIPickerView with 2 components.
I would like to save the user's selection and to apply it next time the pickerView is shown again.

Here's my code:

```
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSUserDefaults *pickerViewSelectionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pickerViewSelectionDefaults setInteger:row forKey:@"pickerViewSelectionKey"];
    [pickerViewSelectionDefaults synchronize];

}

}
```

And...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 

    NSUserDefaults *pickerViewSelectionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pickerView selectRow:[pickerViewSelectionDefaults integerForKey:@"pickerViewSelectionKey"] inComponent:0 animated:YES];

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fail to understand what your real issue is. Your code should work given that you only spin component 0 and not 1. There's an issue with storing the row for two components into one setting. If you spin component 1 to row 20 and then load the view it will most likely crash unless component 0 also has 20 rows.

Please provide an error message or something that indicate what is wrong. Also make sure that your viewWillAppear method is actually called.

Comment: The problem is that even with this NSUserDefaults code, each time the pickerView is shown, the selected index in both components is 0.

Thank you for helping

Comment: Are you sure that viewWillAppear is even called? Also make sure that the picker items has been populated at the time when viewWillAppear is executed.